# How to get weeks as an array for past 2 months from current date in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get weeks for past two months in the following format. Is there  a way i can achieve this in javascript. Any pointers on how to do this will is much appreciated.

```
[   

    {
        "week_start": "8/01/2016",
        "week_end": "8/06/2016"
    }, {
        "week_start": "8/07/2016",
        "week_end": "8/13/2016"
    }, {
        "week_start": "8/14/2016",
        "week_end": "8/20/2016"
    }, {
        "week_start": "8/21/2016",
        "week_end": "8/27/2016"
    }, {
        "week_start": "8/28/2016",
        "week_end": "9/03/2016"
    }, {
        "week_start": "9/04/2016",
        "week_end": "9/10/2016"
    }, {
        "week_start": "9/11/2016",
        "week_end": "9/17/2016"
    }, {
        "week_start": "9/18/2016",
        "week_end": "9/24/2016"
    }, {
        "week_start": "9/25/2016",
        "week_end": "10/01/2016"
    }, {
        "week_start": "10/02/2016",
        "week_end": "10/08/2016"
    }


]
```

Comment: You can use http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I would also suggest using a library like `momentjs`: the vanilla JS solution will force you to use recursion (or a loop), handling the different number of days (a month can be 28,29,30,31). A good exercise, but pointless if you need a quick solution.

Comment: @pietro909 no need to know how many days in a month to do this with native Date. There are built in methods to add/subtract days granted not is clean as moment.js but it's not a complicated issue either

Comment: @charlietfl oh yes you are right: one can search just for day indexes, no matter the number of days in that month. Good point, sorry.

Comment: why does your first week have only 6 days?

Comment: @JaromandaX He's being accurate, August of 2016 started on a Monday, so the first week ended on Saturday, the sixth.

Comment: @DavidMann - so, he really wants the current month plus the previous 2 full months - because 2 months back from today is the 7th August, so why include 1st - 6th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use native javascript Date objects like this

```js
// create two Date objects to act as lower and upper bound
const rightNow = new Date();
const twoMonthsAgo = new Date();
twoMonthsAgo.setMonth( twoMonthsAgo.getMonth() -2 );

// a helper function to advance our iterator by two weeks
const addTwoWeeksTo = (thisDate) => {
  thisDate.setDate( thisDate.getDate() + 7 );
};

// a helper function to output weeks in our desired format
const printWeek = (thisDate) => {
  var oneWeekFromThisDate = new Date( thisDate );
  oneWeekFromThisDate.setDate( oneWeekFromThisDate.getDate() + 7 );
  return {
    "week_start": thisDate.toLocaleString('en-US').split(',').shift(),
    "week_end": oneWeekFromThisDate.toLocaleString('en-US').split(',').shift()
  }
};

let returnObject = [];

// iterate
for (let thisWeek = new Date(twoMonthsAgo); thisWeek < rightNow; addTwoWeeksTo(thisWeek)) {
  returnObject.push( printWeek(thisWeek) );
}

document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(returnObject,null,"\t");
```

```html
<pre><code id="x"></code></pre>
```

Comment: your `week_end` is wrong by one day, you also don't truncate August, and the week wont always start on a Sunday - it will start on the day of the week having the same day of month as the current day of month two months ago ... so it happens to work today (except you missed the first 6 day week of August) if you're still on the seventh October, but here, on the eighth your weeks are wrong and start on a Monday - and your "day" output doesn't have leading zero

Comment: yeah. there are off-by-one errors the OP would need to correct. and if they want weeks to start on sunday or monday they would have to add that logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://momentjs.com/ like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.js">  </script>
<script>
  var startDay = moment("2016-07-24"); //Sunday
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      //console.log('week_start' + startDay.add(i, 'weeks').calendar());
      //console.log('week_end' + startDay.add(i, 'weeks').subtract(1, 'days').calendar());
      res.push({
        'week_start': startDay.add(i, 'weeks').calendar(),
        'week_end': startDay.add(i, 'weeks').subtract(1, 'days').calendar()
      })
  }
  console.log(res)
</script>
```